# Delphi html parsing check if element has attribute

Tags: delphi, html-parsing, mshtml

I have the following procedure:

```
class procedure ParseData(AData: string; var ATextList: TList<string>);
var
  HTMLDoc: OleVariant;
  HTMLElement: OleVariant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  HTMLDoc := coHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2;
  HTMLDoc.Write(AData);
  HTMLDoc.Close;

  for I := 0 to HTMLDoc.body.all.length - 1 do
  begin
    HTMLElement := HTMLDoc.body.all.item(I);

    if HTMLElement.hasAttribute('attr1') then
      ATextList.Add(HTMLElement.innerHTML);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that `hasAttribute` is not working. Funtions and proicedures like `setattribute`, `innerHTML`, `tagName` are working fine. Is there another way to check if an element contains given attribute?

Comment: You could use XPath to select only elements that have that attribute: `//*[@attr1]`. Then you don't need to check whether the attribute is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test for:

```
if not VarIsNull(HTMLElement.getAttribute('attr1')) then
  ATextList.Add(HTMLElement.innerHTML);
```

---

**EDIT:**

`hasAttribute` is implemented in [`IHTMLElement5`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288596(v=vs.85).aspx) interface - it requires IE8 and later, and is not supported in IE7 Standards mode or IE5 (Quirks) mode.

I imported `C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb` (with `tlibimp` tool), and this code works:

```
if (IDispatch(HTMLElement) as IHTMLElement5).hasAttribute('attr1') then...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a specific named attribute like this:

```
function HasAttribute(ANode : IHtmlDomNode; const AttrName : String) : Boolean;
var
  Attrs : IHtmlAttributeCollection;
  A : IHtmlDomAttribute;
  V : OleVariant;
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := ANode.nodeType = 1;
  if not Result then
    Exit;
  Attrs := IDispatch(ANode.Attributes) as IHtmlAttributeCollection;
  for i := 0 to Attrs.length - 1 do begin
    V := i;
    A := IDispatch(Attrs.item(V)) as IHtmlDomAttribute;
    if CompareText(AttrName, A.nodeName) = 0 then
      exit;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestAttributesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  D : IHtmlDomNode;
  AttrName : String;
  Msg : String;
begin
  D := IDispatch(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('input1')) as  IHtmlDomNode;
  AttrName := 'attr1';
  if HasAttribute(D, AttrName) then
    Msg := 'Found'
  else
    Msg := 'Not found';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AttrName + ' : ' + Msg);

  AttrName := 'value';
  if HasAttribute(D, AttrName) then
    Msg := 'Found'
  else
    Msg := 'Not found';
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AttrName + ' : ' + Msg);
end;
```

The reason I'm suggesting using your own HasAttribute function is that the MSHTML parser has a problem with the 'value' attribute of a node as described in my answer to

[Checking whether there are <input> object attribute values in the HTML Code using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187735/checking-whether-there-are-input-object-attribute-values-in-the-html-code-usin)

using the HTML I included:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This has no value attribute.
    <input name="input1" type="text"/>
    <p>This has an empty value attribute.
    <input name="input2" type="text" value=""/>
    <p>This has a value attribute.
    <input name="input3" type="text" value="already has a value"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

you'll find that the DumpItems routine reports that the IHtmlAttributeCollection contains a node named 'value' whether or not there is an attribute with that name in the HTML's source.  See e.g. the results for the first **Input** node.  It's as if the DOM parser synthesizes a 'value' node if there isn't one defined in the node's HTML.

The code's DumpItems reports the following for the sample HTML:

```
Node name: INPUT
     value: 
  147: type: >text<
  158: value: ><
  160: name: >input1<
Node name: INPUT
     value: 
  147: type: >text<
  158: value: ><
  160: name: >input2<
Node name: INPUT
     value: 
  147: type: >text<
  158: value: >already has a value<
  160: name: >input3<
```

Btw, when I first ran my test app, the reported attribute node numbers (147, 158, 160) puzzled me, but the reason turned out to be that each IHtmlDomNode has a whole host of attributes, mainly event handlers, starting with `onchange`.

To save having to look at the other answer, the code of its DumpItems is

```
procedure TForm1.DumpItems;
var
  E : IHtmlElement;
  D : IHtmlDomNode;
  procedure DumpNode(ANode : IHtmlDomNode);
  var
    Attrs : IHtmlAttributeCollection;
    A : IHtmlDomAttribute;
    V : OleVariant;
    i : Integer;
  begin
    Log('Node name', ANode.nodeName);
    V := ANode.nodeValue;
    if not VarIsNull(V) and not VarIsEmpty(V) then
      Log('     value', V)
    else
      Log('     value', '');

    Attrs := IDispatch(ANode.Attributes) as IHtmlAttributeCollection;
    for i := 0 to Attrs.length - 1 do begin
      V := i;
      A := IDispatch(Attrs.item(V)) as IHtmlDomAttribute;
      V := A.nodeValue;
      if (CompareText(A.nodeName, 'Name') = 0) or (CompareText(A.nodeName, 'Input') = 0) or (CompareText(A.nodeName, 'Type') = 0) or (CompareText(A.nodeName, 'Value') = 0) then begin
        if not VarIsNull(V) and not VarIsEmpty(V) then
          Log('  ' + IntToStr(i) + ': ' + A.nodeName, '>' + V + '<')
        else
          Log('  '  + IntToStr(i) + ': '+ A.nodeName, '')
        end;
    end;

  end;

begin
  D := IDispatch(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('input1')) as  IHtmlDomNode;
  DumpNode(D);

  D := IDispatch(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('input2')) as  IHtmlDomNode;
  DumpNode(D);

  D := IDispatch(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('input3')) as  IHtmlDomNode;
  DumpNode(D);
end;
```

Comment: @kobik:  Sorry, I seem to have made at edit to this while you were doing yours.  Could you be so kind as to re-apply yours?